# curry and empty parameter

Tags: javascript, lodash

I'm currently trying myself at currying and have a question regarding empty parameters.
I have a curried function to do an ajax request:

```
var ajax = _.curry(function(method, request){
  if(request === undefined){
    request = {};
  }
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: getUrl(method),
    data: request,
  })
});
```

So I can define various calls:

```
var insert = ajax('insert');
var update = ajax('update');
var del = ajax('delete');
```

which works nicely like this:

```
insert({ id: 1, name: 'something' });
```

But what doesn't work is if I call it without the parameter.
Curried function is called:

```
del({});
```

Curried function is not called:

```
del();
```

Why?

Comment: Ok maybe I should have been more specific with "doesn' work". It does not call the curried function. 
This is a simplified example but getUrl does something like `location.origin + method`
And method should always be provided but request may be undefined/optional

Comment: that's just how currying works

Comment: declare the curried function, call it say, `powder` ... then `var ajax = _.curry(powder);` ... then del can be declared `var del = powder.bind(null, 'delete');` - insert/update remain as they are ... you can call `del()` with or without a parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure someone who understands currying much better than I do can describe this in more depth. However, the way I view currying is that by currying a function, you're intending to "trickle" arguments into the original function. The original function will only be invoked once the expected number of arguments have been trickled in.

Now here's the catch: most examples trickle in exactly one argument, just as you're trying to do:

```
var curried = _.curry(function(foo, bar, baz){
    console.log(foo, bar, baz);
})
curried(1)(2)(3);
// -> 1 2 3
```

And that's all well and good. However, note that you could do this:

```
curried(1)(2,3);
// -> 1 2 3
```

And you'd get the same result. The second and third arguments are trickled in together.

So what you're doing is like this:

```
var fn = curried(1);
fn();
```

The call to `fn` is passing in zero arguments, that is you've trickled zero arguments, so you progress zero arguments towards your goal of running the original function. You can call `fn()` all day long, it will never call the original curried function.

If you call `fn(undefined)` it will (should) work, because you've actually passed an argument, explicitly as `undefined`.

I'm not sure if this is just a lodash implementation detail. I suspect probably not though, because if you expect `fn()` to work, how can it know if you mean `fn(undefined)` or `fn(undefined, undefined)` ad infinitum?